# Locking panels in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS. I have set up several desktops with QGIS to be used by mostly GIS novices in our agency. One of the problems I have encountered is that they accidentally close off one or another of the panels (Legends TOC mostly) and then can't get it back. I would like to set up a configuration that has these panels in tabs how I want them. My question is can I lock this configuration so they cannot inadvertently close off the panels?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that can be done.

First make a `startup.py` file in `.qgis2\python`

Add the following code

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
docks = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget)
for dock in docks:
    dock.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
```

Now on QGIS startup it will remove the close button from all docks.

If you need to only remove it from some set list of docks you can get the name of the docks by doing:

```
for d in docks: 
    print d.objectName()
```

And then using the name of the dock to just set that one:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, "Layers").setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
```